# Javascript Callback function malfunction

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to implement an anonymous callback function.  The code here I wrote is janky I know.

Typing intro is a span, it activates the `.typed` animation with the given parameters.  What I need to activate, and what isn't, is the last function to remove the two elements by id there. Can't figure out how.

```
<!-- Executes intro typing text -->
<script>
  document.getElementById('intro-button').onclick = function() {
    $(function() {
      $("#typing-intro").typed({
             strings: ["&emsp;INITSEG  = DEF_INITSEG</br>&emsp;SYSSEG"],
             typeSpeed: 0,
             backDelay: 20,
             loop: false,
             loopCount: false,
        }, function (){
           document.getElementById("intro-section").remove();
           document.getElementById("typing-intro").remove();
        });
      });
    }
    ///script
</script>
```

Comment: This is `typed.js` right?

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`?

Comment: Yes typed.js   and Lister,  I was told it was good programming style.  Looking it up I was wrong.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: actually mr lister <br /> is best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MinusFour points out, the typed animation function doesn't take a callback function as the final parameter. Instead a "callback" function is passed to it through the options

Beyond the question, there's a lot you can clean up with the code. Since you're using jQuery already, you can clean up the event handler. Instead of `document.getElementById('intro-button').onclick = function() { ... }` you can have `$('#intro-button').click(function() { ... });`. If you are placing this `<script>` in the `<head>`, you will want to wrap the entire thing in in `$(function() { ... })`, not have in stuck in the middle of your code.

Finally, since you're using jQuery everywhere else, instead of document.getElementById("intro-section").remove(); just have $('#intro-section').remove().

So it would like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#intro-button').click(function() {
          $("#typing-intro").typed({
             strings: ["&emsp;INITSEG  = DEF_INITSEG</br>&emsp;SYSSEG"],
             typeSpeed: 0,
             backDelay: 20,
             loop: false,
             loopCount: false,
             callback: function (){
                $("#intro-section").remove();
                $("#typing-intro").remove();
             }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, new to JS and this was on point.  Super super appreciated

Comment: @Kaiido, I didn't realize it was. Thanks for the info. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

`typed.js` doesn't really handle the callback as a separate argument. The method it extends on the jQuery prototype is:

```
$.fn.typed = function(option) {
```

So you'll have to pass it as part of the `callback` key of your `options` object.

```
$("#typing-intro").typed({
             strings: ["&emsp;INITSEG  = DEF_INITSEG</br>&emsp;SYSSEG"],
             typeSpeed: 0,
             backDelay: 20,
             loop: false,
             loopCount: false,
             callback: function (){
                document.getElementById("intro-section").remove();
                document.getElementById("typing-intro").remove();
             }
        });
      });
```

There's also no `remove` method for the `DOMElement`, it's a jquery thing.

```
$('#intro-section').remove();
$('#typing-intro').remove();
```